# Cakephp3: how to get full url to the current page with get parameters after interrogation mark

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to get full current url. On my ctp file, i tried:

```
$this->Url->build(null, true)
```

Or

```
$this->request->here;
```

And tried on Controller file:

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;
Router::url(null, true)
```

But none of those return all parameters after interrogation mark.

Comment: Did you try `$this->request->here(false)` ?

Comment: @SamHecquet thanks, this really return all parameters, but doesn't return base url with donain name, protocol, etc.

Comment: @SamHecquet i tested using your suggestion and it worked for what i wanted, even without domain name, etc. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Network.Request.html#_here), you can get the current requests URL, including the querystring arguments, like this:

```
$this->request->here(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Cake\View\Helper\UrlHelper
$this->Url->build($this->request->here(), true);
```

or

```
use Cake\Routing\Router
Router::url($this->request->here(), true);
```

Both work the same on your CTP file

Comment: My url looks like this:

http://serverName/folderName/cakeProject/controller?parameter1=value&parameter2=value

Using what you proposed first ($this->Url->build($this->request->here(), true);), my url turns to:

http://serverName/folderName/cakeProject/folderName/cakeProject/controller?parameter1=value&parameter2=value

Repeting folderName and cakeProject